# ActionScript passing extra parameter to request when using CallResponder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, blazeds

I am running flex with BlazeDS. My backend is in Java.

I have the following function in actionscript:

```
override public function execute():void
{
        super.execute();
        var responder:CallResponder = new CallResponder(); 
        responder.token = service.foo(param);
        responder.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onDataReceive);
        responder.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT  , onDataReceiveError);
}
```

In Java the function foo looks like this:

```
public void foo (String param) {
   //some code
}
```

Is it possible to somehow pass another parameter on the request without changing the java function foo?

I want to do something like this in foo (ignore the syntax):

```
public void foo (String param) {
   Request.getParameter("param2");
}
```

I hope that's clear.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not restricted to CallResponder. Maybe there is another function I can use that does what CallResponder does but also has this option.  My main goal is not to change the signature of the java function if that's at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that - you need to change the signature of the java method if you want to pass more parameters. Or, you can use a generic Map as an input parameter and push all the parameters into it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you think of anyway to do this so that the java code doesn't need to be changed?

Comment: Cornel is right. You should change the java method signature rather than try to be tricky and sneak another parameter in. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: A complete transformation of all the Java API as well as altering all the Actionscript methods that call them. So basically hours of work times 2 :-).  If there is a way to provide an extra parameter it would only be hours of work. Notice that I don't want to "sneak" in anything. I was wondering if there was a legitimate way to do this.

Comment: Even if you could attach it to the header you would then bypass all of the advantages of BlazeDS..